# Programmatically Adding SerialVersion Ids for Java files

Tags: java, hibernate, serialization, java-5, serialversionuid

We have hundreds of java Entities which are reverse engineered through Hibernate tools. The Entity classes seem to implement `java.io.Serializable` interface, but doesn't have `serialVersionUID`.

We are tasked with adding `serialVersionUID`  to these files (worst case, we'll have to do it manually). Is there some other way we can do it ? An ideal solution will be to do it in the reverse engineering step itself, but it's also okay to pass in the package name and add `serialVersionUID` to the Entity classes.

We are using Hibernate 3.0

Answer (score 2):

I started writing my own code to implement this, but then I found a much simpler solution.
The following bash script runs recursively through your *.java files (run it from the root of your project) and searches all the files implementing Serializable.

```
#!/bin/bash  

files=$(find . -name '*.java' | xargs grep -i -l "Serializable"  | xargs grep "interface" -L | xargs grep "serialVersionUID" -L)
```

then it will print the serialuid it added and to which class

```
do
 serial=$(jot -r 1 1000000000000 9999999999999)
 echo "Adding serialVersionUID $serial to $f"
```

then it will search for the string "implements Serializable" and add under that line the serialVersionUID variable

```
sed -i '' "/implements Serializable/ a\
    private static final long serialVersionUID =${serial}L;
" $f

done
```

Here is the original [post](http://tommasotorti.blogspot.com/2014/02/script-for-adding-serialversionuid-to.html)

Comment: This is for unix based system . I am using a Windows based system.So I guess I will have to spend some time

Comment: Installing cygwin is not an option?